# How to get the "screen" utility to work on MobaXterm?

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions, gnu-screen, mobaxterm

I got this error when I first tried to use the screen utility:

```
$ screen
Directory /tmp/uscreens/S-Wildcard must have mode 700.
```

Oddly enough, I don't seem to get this error again; I get this different error each time now when I try to use `screen`:

```
$ screen
Directory '/tmp/uscreens' must have mode 777.
```

Attempting the chmod the directory has no effect:

```
$ chmod 777 /tmp/uscreens
$ screen
Directory '/tmp/uscreens' must have mode 777.
```

My filesystem is NTFS.  I thought that it therefore didn't support UNIX permission bits, but I discovered that is not *necessarily* the case - https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/457111.  However, I am not sure how to apply that answer to Windows, or if that is the correct fix.

How can I get `screen` to be able to run on my Windows 7 laptop in MobaXterm?

---

**Background, optional reading:**

I use MobaXterm constantly at work (on a Windows 7 laptop).  Most of my time is spent on the command line, logged in to various Linux servers, but also with work done directly (locally) on my own laptop on the command line (still in MobaXterm).

I recently started using "screen" (for remote screen-sharing sessions) and I'd like to get more practice with it - besides being very useful in my remote work (i.e. on servers), I think it will also be more convenient for switching between work spaces than switching between MobaXterm tabs.

---

**Update:** I have a new work laptop running Windows 10, but the above situation still applies exactly.  Answers that will only work on Windows 10 and not Windows 7 are welcome.  (Since Windows 10 has a "Windows Subsystem for Linux," it seems likely that some workaround might exist.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (MobaXterm v11.1, Windows 10 Home) - Run these on a terminal:

```
$ mount
    C:/Tools/MOBAXT~1/slash/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user)
    C:/Tools/MOBAXT~1/slash/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user)
    C:/Tools/MOBAXT~1/slash on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
    C:/Tools/MOBAXT~1/home on /home/Sathya type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user)
    C:/Tools/MOBAXT~1/home on /home/mobaxterm type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user)
    B: on /drives/b type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
    C: on /drives/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
    D: on /drives/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)

$ mkdir /drives/d/Cygwin_Temp  #NOTE: **Create a new dir on a mount point without "noacl"**
$ chmod 700 /drives/d/Cygwin_Temp
$ export SCREENDIR=/drives/d/Cygwin_Temp  #better to add to ~/.bashrc

$ screen
```